# mysql show 0 if selected value is null?

Tags: mysql, null, default-value

I have a long sql query that calculates a few things about payments and shipments. In some cases the value is `null.` I think that's because there's being divided by 0.

Here's a small part of my query:

```
     ROUND(sum(case when shipping_method = 'c' AND (paid_amount - shipping_costs) < 70 then 1 end) * 100 / sum(case when shipping_method = 'c' then 1 end),2) as co_less_70,
```

I think that when this part is 0: `sum(case when shipping_method = 'colissimo' then 1 end),2)` my query shows null. Is there any way to assign a default value for this `co_less_70` column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use the `COALESCE()` function:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce
>   Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

In your code:

```
COALESCE(
    ROUND(sum(case when shipping_method = 'c' AND (paid_amount - shipping_costs) < 70 then 1 end) * 100 / sum(case when shipping_method = 'c' then 1 end),2),
    0
) AS co_less_70
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IFNULL(
  ROUND(sum(case when shipping_method = 'c' AND (paid_amount - shipping_costs) < 70 then 1 end) * 100 / sum(case when shipping_method = 'c' then 1 end),2)
,<default>) AS co_less_70,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default case, but anything except zero :-

```
sum(case when shipping_method = 'colissimo' then 1 else some_value end case),2)
```

Comment: The user want to assign a default value for the entire column when it's `NULL`, not only a default value when the divisor is `0`.

Comment: If there are no rows where shipping_method = 'c', then you'll get 0 / 0 , which is likely what's causing the issue.  This won't fix it -- and any other value will throw off the math.